# Android studio 1.4 is not build properly

Tags: android-studio

When I Update android studio to 1.4 and created new project I'm getting the error,how to solve this problem.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>   peer not authenticated
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the below mentioned path:

Right click on your application/project -> open module settings-> Go to "Dependencies" tab -> you'll find "junit:junit:4.12" -> select it and right click and choose remove option -> ok

Now again try to build your application.

Comment: Acceptable answare

Answer (score 1):

It is problem with proxy! I solved this problem with proxycap program. I installed this program to my mac, after this, solved my problem!

Comment: @moodgod can you please explain me how you solved it